# Only fire selection changed when user selects new item using MVVM in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

### Issue

---

I have set my binding up for my Combo-box which contains and `SelectedItem` and `ItemSource` which binds to my ViewModel properties.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_cameraDevice" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFB03636" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding CameraDeviceList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCameraDevice}" />

public VideoCaptureDeviceInformation SelectedCameraDevice
{
    get { return _selectedCameraDevice; }
    set
    {
         selectedCameraDevice = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCameraDevice");
         SelectedCameraDevice_Changed();

    }
}
private VideoCaptureDeviceInformation _selectedCameraDevice;
```

As you can see from the property, when it changes it will call a method which will do somethings.

The issue is on my load method I populate the combo-box which triggers this property and therefore calls the method.

I only want this method to trigger when a user clicks on the box and changes to a new item.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the SelectedCameraDevice initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you dont want to trigger that action the first time the field is set. Check if its null then:

```
public VideoCaptureDeviceInformation SelectedCameraDevice
{
    get { return _selectedCameraDevice; }
    set
    {
         var oldVal = _selectedCameraDevice;
         _selectedCameraDevice = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCameraDevice");
         if (oldVal != null)
         {
             SelectedCameraDevice_Changed();
         }
    }
}
```